# Javascript toggle button that changes div visibility, and toggles button text

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle

This would be a great deal easier if I could use jQuery, but I'm trying to avoid doing so for a few reasons. Meanwhile, I've gotten some of the script to work - and I'm attempting to add the function to toggle the button text with the state of the div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a){
    var e = document.getElementById(a);
    if(!e) return true;
    if(e.style.display == "none") {
        e.style.display = "block"
    } else {
        e.style.display = "none"
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

That script works, and nicely, with my current button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe('para0')" value="Expanse"><br> 
<div id="para0">TEST TEXT</div>
```

Trying to have the text toggle with the state of the div visibility. Most answers I've seen are using jQuery, and the context I'm putting the script into makes forms a non-option.

Comment: The real trick is trying to do this will plain ol' javascript. The context I'm using this with is going to be very simple and has to be modular, so I want to keep it as self-contained as I can.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

HTML:

```
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
<div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var button = document.getElementById('toggle'),
    text = document.getElementById('text');

button.onclick = function() {
  var isHidden = text.style.display == 'none';
  text.style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none';
};
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/emikux/1/edit

Comment: You can use `this` inside the callback.

Comment: Well that does accomplish what the script does now (in a more compact form) but the real thing I'm trying to tackle is changing the text that shows up inside the button ("Toggle" in your example), so that it will switch back and forth with each onclick from one text to another; on/off for example.

Comment: `button.innerHTML=isHidden?"Expand":"Contract";`

Answer (score 0):

My JS is a little rusty and I can't check this right now, but I think somthing like this will do what you want:

```
<input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe(this,'para0')" value="Expanse"><br> 
<div id="para0">TEST TEXT</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleMe(btn,a){
    var e=document.getElementById(a);
    if(!e)return true;
    if(e.style.display=="none"){
      e.style.display="block";
      btn.value = "Hide";
   }
   else{
      e.style.display="none";
      btn.value = "Show";
   }
   return true;
  }
  </script>
```

Fixed the spacing show /script would show.